# Best way to maintain an object instance across all components even on reload angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, session

I have a login method that returns an user object that can be shared across all components using dependency injection.

```
  login(usuario: Usuario) {
this.http.post<Usuario>(this.baseUrl, {
  username: usuario.username,
  clave: usuario.clave
}).subscribe(data => {
  if (data != null) {
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');
    localStorage.setItem('token', btoa(usuario.username + ':' + usuario.clave));
    this.usuario2 = data;
    this.router.navigate(['/buscador']);

  } else {
    alert('Authentication failed.');
  }
});}
```

The issue is that if I reload the page the object instance is refreshed and can't be reached by the rest of the components. I have tried using a localStorage when you log in that sets the entire object as a json string, and then parse it in the components that I want to use them. This does work in all components except for the AppComponent that can only be reached onInit. So I would like to know what would the best approach to this situation be.

Comment: I think the best approach would be to implement an AuthGuard that protects the routes that need the login data. The AuthGuard can then check if the user is logged in over a different API request instead of the login one and the views/components can then get the data properly from the AuthGuard.

Comment: @MathiasW i'm actually really new to angular, do you know where could I find some documentation to read up on that?

Comment: Refer this link https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-route-guards

Comment: @FlavioAlarcon Check Suryan's link, this https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/ or just search for Angular 6 Authguard or Routerguard

Comment: Will have to read up on that, thank you very much!

Comment: A Resolver Service may also do the trick: https://codeburst.io/understanding-resolvers-in-angular-736e9db71267

Comment: @Suryan after reading that article, I understand that you think it's a good idea to have the user be the token, the difference is that in that article he encodes it using jwt, he's taking the same approach as I am but with that difference (that is actually pretty major), so is that good practice? i'm actually not very sure.

Comment: Well in `AppComponent's ngOnInit` you can have the check on the start of application something like `if getTokenFromStorage` if its there then fine but in all your component you need to make sure to fetch the data from local storage first and if not then from the xhr if the data is static and is not changing time to time and resolvers are there to show the page to the user when you get the data instead of showing user incomplete page before the data being fetched

Comment: Now I think this would be your call what is best suited for your application

Comment: @Suryan Yeah, I mean the user is the same throughout the entire session so saving in the local storage works perfectly, the issue for me was that i didn't know if it was good practice in terms of security, but using jwt solves that for me, What i'm missing right now is a way to force the component to reload once I log int so the app component can know the value of the user and show the navbar after login.

Comment: Then use `rxjs BehaviourSubject` and store the user there, then whenever the subject is changed then the all the subscriber will got to know about the state and I suggest also store in the local storage, can make a small demo of it, if you say so...

Comment: If you can do that for me I would really appreciate it, Thanks!.